# Opening a new window to show a wider-than-the-browser image, and having the rightmost part showing

Tags: html, css

I would like to find a way to have the image scroll to the right (preferably without animation but I'll take animation as well)

### requirements

1. this for a page that is a window that is being opened where the html is being generated on the fly (i.e. there is no file being loaded). The purpose of which is to show an image. The image is wider than the browser and I would like it to be showing the rightmost part, hence the scroll to the right.
2. preferably no javascript in the spawned window. I investigated this last night and I couldn't easily figure out how to use `innerHTML` to insert script. If the only way is to use javascript then I guess I'm open to that.

I spent a lot of time investigating this last night, and couldn't figure it out. The closest I came was `float: right`... this is almost perfect, except I couldn't figure out how to show the scrollbars. And scrollbars are essential here, so I can view the left side of the image.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I’m unclear how the page is being generated if there is no JavaScript and/or no file download. Could you explain a bit more what is happening, preferably including a bit of code which may make things clearer.

Comment: Hi, there is javascript in the main page that opens the window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see how this can be done without some JS on the new page loading.

This code scrolls the page once the image is loaded using the JS scroll function. The amount to be scrolled is the natural width of the image minus the viewport width.

```
<button onclick="showimg();">Click me to show image</button>
<script>
function showimg() {
  newWindow = window.open("","newwindow");
  newWindow.document.write("<img src='https://picsum.photos/id/1015/3000/1000' onload='window.scroll(this.width - window.innerWidth, 0);'>");
}
</script>
```

Comment: I haven't used javascript in a long time, so I'm rusty. I was having trouble last night getting jquery to work in in the new window when I was injecting code there via innerHTML. Apparently it is a security issue. I was thus assuming all javascript in the new window would be a problem.. but now that I see your code I'm wondering if it is just javascript libraries or code in HEAD injected by innerHTML that is the problem. I will try your code out later, thanks.

Comment: I also would like to scroll the original page when it opens to the far right.. it consists of a table full of images, all the same width, that are usually wider than the browser window (I mean it depends how wide you make your browser window). No need to write the full code but if you could point me in the right direction as to what events and properties/methods to use, then I can go googling.

Comment: Why isn't it basically the same idea? onload use JS to scroll to the right?